# netty - ssl/tls two way authentication

Tags: netty, android-9.0-pie

I already tried [Two way SSL authentication in Netty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597663/two-way-ssl-authentication-in-netty)

but the example is not showing any info anymore, just a 404 Not Found. I have found some help here:

https://github.com/code4craft/netty-learning/blob/master/netty-3.7/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatSslContextFactory.java

but my code still fails after doing what is told allthough my code does not use the exact same api-calls as the sslchat (order of managers added to init).

Here is my code and the error. The error does not indicate which ssl/tls error it is. I have checked both certificates/private keys (for both sides of the client/server) using just one way auth and encryption and it works.

Server side code:

```
    KeyStore serverKeyStore = handleServerKeystore(sipListener);
KeyManagerFactory serverKmf = KeyManagerFactory
                                            .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
clientKeyStore.load(null, SipListener.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
for (ClientCertificate clientCertCert : sipListener.getClientCertificates()) {
Certificate clientCert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
                                                .generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                                        clientCertCert.getClientCertificate().getBytes()));
                                        clientKeyStore.setCertificateEntry(clientCertCert.getClientCertificateAlias(),
                                                clientCert);
                                    }

KeyStore.Builder serverBuilder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance(serverKeyStore,
                                            new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(SipListener.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray()));
KeyStore.Builder clientBuilder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance(clientKeyStore,
                                            new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(SipListener.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray()));
                                    serverKmf.init(new KeyStoreBuilderParameters(
                                            Arrays.asList(new KeyStore.Builder[] { serverBuilder, clientBuilder })));

// Initialize the SSLContext to work with our key managers.
SslContext serverContext = SslContextBuilder.forServer(serverKmf).build();

SSLEngine sslEngine = serverContext.newEngine(ch.alloc());
SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters();
List<SNIMatcher> matchers = new LinkedList<>();
SNIMatcher matcher = new SNIMatcher(0) {

                                        @Override
                                        public boolean matches(SNIServerName serverName) {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    };
matchers.add(matcher);
params.setSNIMatchers(matchers);
sslEngine.setSSLParameters(params);
//sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);
sslEngine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
cp.addFirst("ssl", new SslHandler(sslEngine));
//More codecs follow
```

Client side code:

```
SslContextBuilder sslBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forClient();
SslContext cont2 = null;
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory
                                .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore serverKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
serverKeyStore.load(
                                new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                        decoder.decode(sipSettingsBean.getSipSettingsServerBeans().get(0).getKeystoreB64().getBytes())),
SipListener.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
if (!serverKeyStore.isKeyEntry(sipSettingsBean.getSipSettingsServerBeans().get(0).getKeystoreAlias()))
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                    "Server Keystore file has no matching key for given alias.");
keyManagerFactory.init(serverKeyStore,
                                SipListener.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
sslBuilder.keyManager(keyManagerFactory);

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
// truststore
KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
clientKeyStore.load(null, SipListener.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
for (Cert clientCertCert : sipSettingsBean.getSipSettingsServerBeans().get(0).getCerts()) {
Certificate clientCert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
                                    .generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                            clientCertCert.getCert().getBytes()));
clientKeyStore.setCertificateEntry(
                                    clientCertCert.getAlias(), clientCert);
if (!clientKeyStore.isCertificateEntry(clientCertCert.getAlias()))
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                        "Client Keystore file has no matching key for given alias.");
                        }

trustManagerFactory.init(clientKeyStore);
sslBuilder.trustManager(trustManagerFactory);

cont2 = sslBuilder.build();
SSLEngine engine = cont2.newEngine(ch.alloc(), toHostname,
                                portDestination);
engine.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters();
List<SNIMatcher> matchers = new LinkedList<>();
SNIMatcher matcher = new SNIMatcher(0) {

                            @Override
                            public boolean matches(SNIServerName serverName) {
                              return true;
                            }
                        };
matchers.add(matcher);
params.setSNIMatchers(matchers);
engine.setSSLParameters(params);
ch.pipeline().addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine, false));
//More codecs follow
```

Error on client side:

```
2019-01-26 18:18:54.784 31491-31672/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx D/no.tobiassenit.sipclient.network.RegisterAttemptSSL: request sent
2019-01-26 18:18:54.786 31491-31672/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx D/no.tobiassenit.sipclient.network.RegisterAttemptSSL: request did not time out
2019-01-26 18:18:54.789 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Read error: ssl=0x774f846f08: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
2019-01-26 18:18:54.789 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err: error:10000412:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:592 0x774f890d08:0x00000001)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.789 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.790 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.790 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.790 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.790 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.790 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.790 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.790 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.790 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.790 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.791 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.791 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.791 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.791 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.791 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.791 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.791 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.792 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Read error: ssl=0x774f846f08: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
2019-01-26 18:18:54.792 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err: error:10000412:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:592 0x774f890d08:0x00000001)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.792 31491-31771/v W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:331)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.792 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(ConscryptEngine.java:1138)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.792 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:893)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.792 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:713)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.792 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:678)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.793 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Java8EngineWrapper.unwrap(Java8EngineWrapper.java:236)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.793 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:294)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.793 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1275)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.793 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1177)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.793 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1221)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.793 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.793 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.793 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:   ... 16 more
2019-01-26 18:18:54.794 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x774f846f08: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
2019-01-26 18:18:54.794 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err: error:10000412:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:592 0x774f890d08:0x00000001)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.794 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.794 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:521)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.794 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1099)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.794 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataHeap(ConscryptEngine.java:1119)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.795 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1091)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.795 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:841)
2019-01-26 18:18:54.795 31491-31771/xx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx W/System.err:   ... 25 more
```

Error on server side:

```
 io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1441)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1275)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1177)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1221)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    ... 16 moreCaused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:201)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1672)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:309)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:297)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientCertificate(ServerHandshaker.java:1942)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:236)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:984)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:924)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:921)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1379)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1435)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1343)
    ... 20 more
```

|

And of course: netty: 4.1.28.Final, Win10 and java version "1.8.0_151"

I tried netty 4.1.33.Final as well. Same result.

As you may have noticed I have ignored the test for hostname in the engine. This might be just for the server handshake and not for the client (private key) handshake. Please advice if you can on how to ignore the client hostname part of the handshake as well unless it is already done (I have tried doing it on both sides) as my application will not be able to support a dns name for the client. (It will be able to support it for the server but for the moment ignoring it).

I tried netty 4.1.34.Final-20190208.192045-20. Same result.
I tried netty 4.1.34.Final. Same result.
I tried netty 4.1.35.Final-SNAPSHOT. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem while performing two way SSL with Netty. I solved it by using following configuration:

```
public HttpClient getHttpClient(HttpClientProperties properties){

        // configure pool resources
        HttpClientProperties.Pool pool = properties.getPool();

        ConnectionProvider connectionProvider;
        if (pool.getType() == DISABLED) {
            connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider.newConnection();
        }
        else if (pool.getType() == FIXED) {
            connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider.fixed(pool.getName(),
                    pool.getMaxConnections(), pool.getAcquireTimeout());
        }
        else {
            connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider.elastic(pool.getName());
        }

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(connectionProvider)
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> {

                    if (properties.getConnectTimeout() != null) {
                        tcpClient = tcpClient.option(
                                ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                                properties.getConnectTimeout());
                    }

                    // configure proxy if proxy host is set.
                    HttpClientProperties.Proxy proxy = properties.getProxy();

                    if (StringUtils.hasText(proxy.getHost())) {

                        tcpClient = tcpClient.proxy(proxySpec -> {
                            ProxyProvider.Builder builder = proxySpec
                                    .type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                                    .host(proxy.getHost());

                            PropertyMapper map = PropertyMapper.get();

                            map.from(proxy::getPort).whenNonNull().to(builder::port);
                            map.from(proxy::getUsername).whenHasText()
                                    .to(builder::username);
                            map.from(proxy::getPassword).whenHasText()
                                    .to(password -> builder.password(s -> password));
                            map.from(proxy::getNonProxyHostsPattern).whenHasText()
                                    .to(builder::nonProxyHosts);
                        });
                    }
                    return tcpClient;
                });

        HttpClientProperties.Ssl ssl = properties.getSsl();
        if (ssl.getTrustedX509CertificatesForTrustManager().length > 0
                || ssl.isUseInsecureTrustManager()) {
            httpClient = httpClient.secure(sslContextSpec -> {
                // configure ssl
                SslContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forClient();

                X509Certificate[] trustedX509Certificates = ssl
                        .getTrustedX509CertificatesForTrustManager();
                if (trustedX509Certificates.length > 0) {
                    sslContextBuilder.trustManager(trustedX509Certificates);
                }
                else if (ssl.isUseInsecureTrustManager()) {
                    sslContextBuilder
                            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE);
                }


                sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContextBuilder)
                        .defaultConfiguration(ssl.getDefaultConfigurationType())
                        .handshakeTimeout(ssl.getHandshakeTimeout())
                        .closeNotifyFlushTimeout(ssl.getCloseNotifyFlushTimeout())
                        .closeNotifyReadTimeout(ssl.getCloseNotifyReadTimeout())
                        .handlerConfigurator(
                                (handler)->{
                                    SSLEngine engine = handler.engine();
                                    //engine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
                                    SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters();
                                    List<SNIMatcher> matchers = new LinkedList<>();
                                    SNIMatcher matcher = new SNIMatcher(0) {

                                        @Override
                                        public boolean matches(SNIServerName serverName) {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    };
                                    matchers.add(matcher);
                                    params.setSNIMatchers(matchers);
                                    engine.setSSLParameters(params);
                                }
                        )
                ;
            });
        }

        return httpClient;

    }
```

The above code snippet uses `handlerConfigurator` provided by netty's Builder present inside the `SslProvider` class to customize the `SslHandler` to avoid hostname matching.